# Why does the compiler interpret assignment as definition

Tags: c, linux, gcc

A sample c program is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 10;
i = 25;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

When it is compiled using `gcc`, it throws redefinition error.

```
warning: data definition has no type or storage class
i = 25;
^
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘i’ [-Wimplicit-int]
error: redefinition of ‘i’
note: previous definition of ‘i’ was here
int i = 10;
```

I have reassigned a value to that variable `i`. Why does the compiler interpret it as a redefinition?

Comment: Outside functions C doesn't allow assignments apart from initialisation.

Comment: Only declarations are possible at global scope, and data type is optional and defaults to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

you can declare a variable outside of function and initialize it. but this `i = 25;` is wrong because  assigning a value to variable should be done inside of 
a function.

```
int i = 10;

int main(void)
{
    i = 25;//this should be inside of function
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

also as @rustyx mentioned in comments default data type of global variable is `int` ,so here `i = 25;`, it's like you are redefining `int i` , not assigning a value to it.

Comment: You are correct, however, the more fundamental reason is that `i=25;` is a _statement_ and statements are run-time, _Therefore_ statements can only occur in functions, as functions are what is executed.